# C++ Using list.remove() causes a segmentation fault when used by multiple threads

Tags: c++, concurrency, pthreads

I am simulating customers with threads sitting at and then leaving tables. My current data structure for the table is a list that holds thread pointers.

```
list<intptr_t> table;

void * customer(void* vargp){
    intptr_t tid;
    tid = (intptr_t)vargp;
    //enter table
    table.push_back(tid);

    //do actions at table

    //leave table   
    table.remove(tid);
}
```

I am having an intermittent segmentation fault that I am pretty sure comes from two threads trying to remove themselves from the table at the same time. Using gdb, this is the backtrace I found:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x2aaacf005700 (LWP 44705)]
0x00000000004032db in std::_List_const_iterator<long>::operator++ (this=0x2aaacf004e10) at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_list.h:235
235             _M_node = _M_node->_M_next;
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.17-324.el7_9.x86_64 libgcc-4.8.5-44.el7.x86_64 libstdc++-4.8.5-44.el7.x86_64
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000000004032db in std::_List_const_iterator<long>::operator++ (this=0x2aaacf004e10) at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_list.h:235
Python Exception <type 'exceptions.ValueError'> Cannot find type std::_List_const_iterator<long>::_Node:
Python Exception <type 'exceptions.ValueError'> Cannot find type std::_List_const_iterator<long>::_Node:
#1  0x0000000000402c6b in std::__distance<std::_List_const_iterator<long> > (__first=, __last=) at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_iterator_base_funcs.h:82
Python Exception <type 'exceptions.ValueError'> Cannot find type std::_List_const_iterator<long>::_Node:
Python Exception <type 'exceptions.ValueError'> Cannot find type std::_List_const_iterator<long>::_Node:
#2  0x0000000000402386 in std::distance<std::_List_const_iterator<long> > (__first=, __last=) at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_iterator_base_funcs.h:118
#3  0x0000000000401d31 in std::list<long, std::allocator<long> >::size (this=0x606430 <table3>) at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_list.h:874
#4  0x0000000000401295 in customer (vargp=0xd) at project2.cc:129
#5  0x00002aaaab4f6ea5 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#6  0x00002aaaab8099fd in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

From this, I am pretty sure my problem lies with the remove() function, but I don't know how to fix it. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Standard containers are not meant to be accessed asynchronously. You must synchronize access (both the insert and remove) to the list yourself.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I was not aware of this

Comment: What Yksisarvinen said is mostly true. But it's worth noting that C++ does provide some guarantees about concurrent access to container elements. In particular, concurrent access (reading or writing) to _different_ elements of the same container is always safe, with the exception of `vector<bool>` (per 22.2.2,  [N4861](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4861.pdf)).

Comment: And `vector<bool>` is such a weird-o that it usually [gets its own documentation page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool).

Comment: Use a lock. Like `std::mutex` or similar if you access the container from multiple threads.

Comment: FYI: If you are using a recent enough vintage of C++ that it supports `std::thread`, then you should not be using Posix threads (pthreads.)

Answer (score 3):

Never modify an object in one thread when another thread is, or might be, accessing it unless you are using an object that is specifically documented to permit that type of concurrency.